# Increasing logging verbosity of class being unit-tested in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

I have a Python class that uses the logging module to provide some debug output:

**File someclass.py:**

```
import logging

class SomeClass:

    def do_stuff(self):
        # do some things
        logging.debug("I just did some stuff")
        # do some more stuff
        return True
```

I do unit testing on this class with the unittest module

**File test_someclass.py**

```
import unittest
from someclass import SomeClass

class SomeClassTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_do_stuff(self):
        obj = SomeClass()
        self.assertFalse(obj.do_stuff())

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I want to do is show the debug messages while I am running the unit tests. I tried to set the verbosity to debug from the unit test module:

```
import logging

# ....

def main():
    unittest.main()
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This didn't work. What would be the way to achieve this? Even better would be enabling DEBUG verbosity for only one test.

UPDATE:

Apparently it works when running it from the Python shell, but not in PyDev (it probably uses a different test runner).

Comment: Do you want to output debug messages every time the test runs, or are you ok if debug message would show up on failures only?

Comment: If they come up on failures only, then it's even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output debug messages on failures only, using [`nose`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) test runner would be the easiest way to go since `nose` [captures stdout](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/capture.html) and print it out on failures. It works out of the box:

```
$ nosetests test.py
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_stuff (test.SomeClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/../../test.py", line 7, in test_stuff
    self.assertFalse(True)
AssertionError: True is not false
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
I just did some stuff

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

where `test.py` contains:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class SomeClass(TestCase):
    def test_stuff(self):
        print "I just did some stuff"
        self.assertFalse(True)
```

Comment: Sounds cool, but I can't install anything in our Linux environment (no permissions).

Comment: @Tudor as far as I understand, you can just use `print` and you will see the message on the console on failure.

Comment: @Tudor I mean, no `nose` required here. Just put a `print` before the assertion failure line and see the output.

Comment: Adapter my code, tried it out and it doesn't work. I see that you made SomeClass inherit from TestCase. This is not the setup above. I have a class that spits out debug messages and a separate testcase class. If the tested class doesn't issue messages to stdout (because DEBUG is not enabled, then there is nothing to redirect).

Comment: I found that PyDev also has nose integrated, so I switched to that. Thanks for the tip. It's working perfectly (only showing debug info for failed tests).

Answer (score 1):

call `unittest.main()` from your `main()`.

```
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    unittest.main()
```

My output shows:

```
DEBUG:root:I just did some stuff
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

The basic example on unittests docs at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html shows the simple way of calling and running a unit test from main.

Comment: This is because you put all code in the same module. I have 2 modules, one for the class and one for the unit tests. The unittest.main() was there in my original code, I just removed it for brevity. Splitting the code into 2 modules will not show the debug message.

Comment: @Tudor hm, I've tried this approach with the setup you've provided. It works for me. Could you recheck if it works for you? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe You're right, it does work when calling `python test_someclass.py`. I was calling it in Eclipse/PyDev and there it wasn't working. It apparently uses another test runner.